# Is there a t test table in python (numpy, scipy etc)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am trying as an exercise since I'm still fairly new to python and programming to make a script that takes a one sample pool of numbers and just use the t value from a table to make a more accurate deviation than a stdev.

**example:** *10 samples and I want the t table value from the column for 0.975.
In this case it's 10-1, row 9 has the t value 2.262 in column 0.975*

Is there any easy way to just type into python or any extra library that I just want the t value from row X column 0.975 and use it in further calculations?

Or do I have to find a CVS file and try and import values in that way?
I have tried to go through scipy.stats functions but honestly its a bit overwhelming for someone just starting out and haven't done anything with p values or similar statistics before.

Comment: I believe you are looking for https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `ppf` method (i.e. the quantile function) of [`scipy.stats.t`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html):

```
In [129]: from scipy.stats import t

In [130]: alpha = 0.025

In [131]: t.ppf(1 - alpha, df=9)
Out[131]: 2.2621571627409915
```

`t.ppf()` ultimately calls [`scipy.special.stdtrit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.stdtrit.html), so you could also use that function and avoid the slight overhead of going through `t.ppf()`:

```
In [141]: from scipy.special import stdtrit

In [142]: alpha = 0.025

In [143]: stdtrit(9, 1 - alpha)
Out[143]: 2.2621571627409915
```

(If you are wondering how the function ended up with the name `stdtrit`, it is the **S**tudent **T** **D**is**TR**ibution function **I**nverse with respect to **T**.  Clear, right?)

Comment: Hmm interesting solution. btw can i replace "1-alpha" with for example:
alpha = 0.975
df = 9
t.ppf (alpha, df)

and get the same results?

Comment: Yes, you can replace `1 - alpha` with the actual value.  I wrote it that way because it is common to refer to the significance level of the t-test as "alpha"  (e.g. https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/statprogram/node/137, https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/statprogram/node/137).

Comment: Ahh well I'm self teaching so i don't know the real praxis. but good to know if I ever make something to share.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find one directly in Python, but I found [rpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpy2/) which makes a lot of R functionality available in Python, also their t.test functionalities.